# C++ many errors when defining string

Tags: c++, string

Hello i am learning C++ and i have errors while making VISUAL APP NOT CONSOLE

My problem is at the string **Num1 = "0"**;

Please explain to me why this is happening?

The string is 0 because i want to make calculator so i need to make Num1 + "TheClicked number"

```
<script>
#include <windows.h>

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "Andrey App";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument,
                    int nFunsterStil)

{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "Andrey App",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
    string Num1 = "0";
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Beep"),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     20, 50, 80, 25,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);    

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("2"),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     120, 50, 30, 30,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);  
        CreateWindow(L"STATIC", Num1, 
                     WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                     20, 20, 300, 230,
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);  
        break;
    }

      case WM_COMMAND:
      {
       if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
           Beep(40, 50);
       }

       if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) {
           if(Num1 == 0){
              Num1 = 2;
              }
              else{
              Num1 + "2";
              }
       }

       break;
       }

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <string>`, `using std::string;`, move the declaration of `Num1` before the `switch`, and replace `Num1` in the `CreateWindow` call with `Num1.c_str()`

Comment: @oldrinb: you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it should look:

```
//At the top of your .cpp file

#include<string>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static std::string Num1 = "0";    /* static string created once and keeps it contents for each function call */
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Beep"),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     20, 50, 80, 25,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);    

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("2"),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     120, 50, 30, 30,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);  
        ///CreateWindow takes a LPCSTR as second arg, which is wchar_t under the covers, so need to convert
        std::wstring wstr(Num1.begin(), Num1.end());
        CreateWindow(L"STATIC", wstr.c_str(), //.c_str() returns a const char* 
                     WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                     20, 20, 300, 230,
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);  
        break;
    }

      case WM_COMMAND:
      {
       if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
           Beep(40, 50);
       }

       if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) {
           if(Num1 == "0"){ //Num1 is a string, so you should check a string
              Num1 = "2";
              }
              else{
              Num1 += "2";
              }
       }

       break;
       }

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not working got error on         CreateWindow(L"STATIC", Num1.c_str(), 
                     WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                     20, 20, 300, 230,
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL); at the last line argument 2